# The plugin "transform-class-properties" didn't export a Plugin instance

Tags: babeljs

I am willing to use ES6/7 [transform class properties](https://github.com/jeffmo/es-class-fields-and-static-properties) feature using Babel. 
Following the steps mentioned [here](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/). I have created a .babelrc file with contents:

```
{
  "plugins": ["transform-class-properties"]
}
```

On executing `webpack -p` following error shows up:

```
ERROR in ./src/main.js
Module build failed: TypeError: The plugin "transform-class-properties" didn't export a Plugin instance
    at PluginManager.validate (../node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/plugin-manager.js:164:13)
```

Any idea whats wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`transform-class-properties` is a Babel 6 plugin, and you are trying to use it with Babel 5. In Babel 5, you would do

```
"optional": ["es7.classProperties"]
```

or update to Babel 6.

Comment: Upgraded to Babel 6. Thanks :)